# Show that the solution of the ODE is valid provided that $\eta$ satisfies $(A-2I)\eta=a\xi_1+b\xi_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the linear system of ODEs
$$\underline{x}' = A\underline{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
3 &1  &1 \\ 
 0&  2& 0\\ 
 -1&-1  &1 
\end{pmatrix}\underline{x}$$

I have shown that the eigenvalue is $\lambda=2$ with an algebraic multiplicity of 3 and geometric multiplicity of 2, and that the eigenvectors are $\underline\xi_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\underline\xi_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}$.

However I've also been asked to show that $\underline{x}_3(t)=(a\underline\xi_1+b\underline\xi_2)te^{2t}+\underline\eta e^{2t}$ is a solution provided that $\underline\eta$ satisfies $(A-2I)\underline\eta=a\underline\xi_1+b\underline\xi_2$, and I have no idea how to show this.

I've been able to compute $\underline\eta$ and $\underline x_3(t)$ as required, but any help regarding showing this property would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what $\underline{x}_3$ should be, is it a component of $\underline{x}$ ?

Comment: @Physor it's one of the solutions of the ODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given solution we have
$$
x_3(t)=(a \xi_1+b \xi_2)te^{2t}+\eta e^{2t} \implies x_3'(t)=(a \xi_1+b \xi_2)(2t+1)e^{2t}+2\eta e^{2t}
$$
from the condition we have
$$
(A-2I)\eta=a\xi_1+b\xi_2 \implies A\eta= 2\eta +a\xi_1+b\xi_2 \tag{1}
$$
and since $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ to the eigenvalue $2$ we have
$$
A\xi_1 = 2\xi_1, \qquad A\xi_2 = 2\xi_2 \tag{2}
$$
Now act on the solution by $A$
\begin{align}
 Ax_3 &= A((a \xi_1+b \xi_2)te^{2t}+\eta e^{2t})\\
&= A(a \xi_1+b \xi_2)te^{2t}+A\eta e^{2t}\\
\text{by $(1)$ and $(2)$ } &= 2(a \xi_1+b \xi_2)te^{2t}+[2\eta +(a\xi_1+b\xi_2)] e^{2t}\\
&= (a \xi_1+b \xi_2)(2t+1)e^{2t}+2\eta e^{2t}\\
&= x_3'
\end{align}

Comment: In the last equation 2nd and 3rd line, why is it that you can simply swap A with 2?

Comment: since the vectors $\xi_1,\xi_2$ are eigenvectors to the eigenvalues $2$, got it ?

Comment: ah ok I see, thanks so much

Comment: you're welcome!